# I've reached the max number of IF statements, and need help to optimise my formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating a spreadsheet to reconstruct an HTML export into an editable daily schedule.

The export contains info on what each person is scheduled to do throughout the day, and the spreadsheet turns it into a format with hourly columns.

Source data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiabY.jpg

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsiv9.jpg

To do this, I've broken down what each person is doing into separate start and end columns, and used nested IF statements to piece it together.

The issue is that I've come up against the maximum amount of nesting, and I still need to add more, as there are more activities to cover. I'd like to know if there's another way I could go about it which wouldn't cause this issue.

The formula looks like this:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4bZm.jpg

It's just saying that if the activity is on or before the current time, and hasn't ended yet, then it should show that activity.

Each line references a type of activity. The referenced cells look like this:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3v54.jpg

There's a lot of repetition in the formula, and I hope there's a way to handle it so that each type of activity doesn't need it's own IF statement. However, I'm kind of stuck here. If there's anyone who knows a way I could change this, I'd really appreciate the help.

EDIT: Formula

IF(AND(OR(P[@6]=X!Z4, [@M]=X!Z4), S[@5] <> X!Z4), X!Z4,

IF(AND(OR(P[@6]=X!Z5, [@M]=X!Z5), S[@5] <> X!Z5), X!Z5,

IF(AND(OR(P[@6]=X!Z6, [@M]=X!Z6), S[@5] <> X!Z6), X!Z6,

...ad nauseam

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you please edit your question and type in your formula?

Comment: Where is your formula?

Comment: Looking at your formula, I can't help but think there is a better way to do this with a formula, perhaps with a `SumProduct()` or similar array-ish type formula. Can you share more about your input data, and this full formula (in text, not picture because we don't want to have to retype everything from an imgur pic) and perhaps we can help with a rewrite. The other option is to write a VBA UDF which would help encapsulate all of this logic in a more robust code besides excel formula nesting.

Comment: I've added the formula into the question - thanks for the tip!

Comment: The source data is structured in such a way that I can't really post it on here outside of the image. Each person's data is structured with the activity type along the top, and the start/end time in the cell below.   The names are stacked vertically. Let me know if I can provide more info.

Comment: For a robust solution, I suggest you use VBA. Return to the original HTML document (which you have not provided an example of); parse out the details, (perhaps into a user defined object), and then report the data that you want in the format that you want.